# Trigonometry/spherical angles/minimum-least-squares

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, least-squares, trigonometric-functions

An issue from 3D tessellated geometry: Find the direction vector of a plane that minimizes the silhouette of a set of triangles. To say it another way, find the direction vector that is most perpendicular to a set of triangles. Each triangle area is half of the length of the normal vector of any two sides—call it $n_i$. The projected area is simply the dot product of these face vectors with the target plane normal, $a$.  Some of these could be negative, so we square and sum—this is a minimal least squares problem: minimize.
$$
f(a)=\sum_i (a \cdot n_i)^2 \text{ over all } a \in \mathbb{S}_2.
$$
This could be done with constrained optimization by creating a Lagrangian, but this seems to lead to a set of nonlinear equations.
Instead, use the spherical angles and redefine $a$ as:
$$
a = [\cos\phi \sin\theta, \sin\phi \sin\theta, \cos\theta]
$$
The derivative of the gradient of $f$ could be set to zero and we solve for the angles: $\phi$ and $\theta$.
Here are those two equations:
$$
\frac{df}{d\phi} =2(x_{ni} \cos\phi \sin\theta+y_{ni}\sin\phi \sin\theta +z_{ni}\cos\theta)(y_{ni}\sin\theta \cos\phi-x_{ni}\sin\theta sin\phi)=0
$$
$$
\frac{df}{d\theta}=2(x_{ni} \cos\phi \sin\theta+y_{ni}\sin\phi \sin\theta +z_{ni}\cos\theta)((x_{ni}\cos\phi+y_{ni}\sin\phi)\cos\theta-z_{ni}\sin\theta)=0
$$

Now, here's where I get confused! I essentially have two terms on the left hand sides that could be zero in each equation. Given that the first big term $(x_{ni} \cos\phi \sin\theta+y_{ni}\sin\phi \sin\theta +z_{ni}\cos\theta)$ is the same in both equations, this being zero won't help us since our equations will reduce to one. and we need two to solve for the two variables ($\phi$ and $\theta$).

The latter two parenthetical terms then make for some nice equations that we can reduce to:
$$\phi = \arctan(y_{ni} / x_{ni})$$
and $$\theta = \arctan((x_{ni}\cos\phi+y_{ni}\sin\phi) / z_{ni})$$

Gee, I'm smart! I code this up and give it a try where the sum of normals results in:
$x_{ni} = 500; y_{ni}= -800; z_{ni} = -0.06$. Clearly the answer should be mostly in the $z$-direction but as you can see from these last two equations, it is clearly not!
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is $a * n_i$? Is it the dot product of vectors?

Comment: Yes. Let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: Is your notation misleading you? I think that the two partial derivatives are concealing an implicit sum over $i$, so they don't have a common factor.

Comment: Three errors. When you computed the partial derivatives, you forgot the sums over $i$. I do not see what $x_{ni},y_{ni},z_{ni}$ means. Last, $\tan \phi = y/x$ does not imply $\phi = \arctan(y/x)$, since $\phi$ is not necessarily in $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$.

Comment: The terms $x_{ni}$, $y_{ni}$, $z_{ni}$ in the partial derivatives are (or rather should be) the sums over $i$. Instead of $x_{ni}$, it would have been more correct of me to write $\sum x_{ni}$. I just dropped the sigma for conciseness.

Comment: The range of $\phi$ and $\theta$ can be in the range of $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. The answer only needs to be in a hemisphere of the space since the projection plane can be either "above" or "below". In other words, the space has bi-symmetry.

Comment: I realize now that I am thinking only of finding a stationary point. In my example above - the solution I found was the maximum not the minimum. Still how do I get all the stationary points from this?

Comment: @mattica. You mean that $x_{n_i}$ is the first coordinate of $n_i$?

Comment: "most perpendicular"? -- оr rather "most parallel"?

Comment: yes, that's right, @WlodAA. two comments above I realized my error here. this exercise finds any extrema (or stationary point). So, one should be able to find the direction that maximizes the projected area as well. or the "most perpendicular" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use constrained optimization, you do get linear equations.
I set $g(x)=||x||^2$. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$,
$$\nabla f(x) = \sum_i 2(x \cdot n_i)n_i \text{ and } \nabla g(x) = 2x.$$
You look at (unit) vectors $x$ such that $\nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x)$ for some real number $\lambda$, namely you look at eigenvectors of the symmetric endomorphism $u$ given by
$$u(x) = \sum_i (x \cdot n_i)n_i.$$
Actually, using an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $u$, you get that the minimum of $f(x) = x \cdot u(x)$ over all $x \in \mathbb{S}_2$ is achieved when $x$ is an eigenvector associated to the least eigenvalue of $u$.

This can be proved directly. Call $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \lambda_3$ the eigenvalues of $u$ and call $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ an orthonormal basis of associated eigenvectors. Then for every $x = \xi_1e_1+\xi_2e_2+\xi_1e_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$,
$$f(x) = x \cdot u(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i\xi^2 \ge \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_1\xi^2 = \lambda_1||x||^2,$$and equality holds when $x$ is a multiple of $e_1$.

Comment: You may be onto something here, but I don't get the symmetric endomorphism part. How do you ensure that $g(x)=||x||^2 - 1 = 0$?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the first question. The symmetry is just that for every vectors $x$ and $y$, $u(x) \cdot y = x \cdot u(y)$, which follows from the definition of $u$. To have $||x||^2=1$, you choose a unit eigenvector for the least eigenvalue. If you take a eigenvector with norm $r$, you minimize $f$ on the sphere $S(0,r)$.

Comment: But the lagrangian gives us 3 homogenous equations (all set to zero). So, isn't the only solution to $Ax=0$ just $x=0$?

Comment: No, $\nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x)$ for some real number $\lambda$ if and only if $x$ belongs to some eigenspace of $u$.

Comment: Ah yes. I see it now!